# How to convert from &#963;&#954; to σκ?

Tags: php, url

I need to put greek letters into a URL, for example: www.example.com?id=σκ
I have the string σκ like this: `&#963;&#954;`
What function can I use in PHP to convert from `&#963;&#954;` to σκ?

Thank you,
phpheini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html_entity_decode` AND `urlencode` - because you shouldn't put special greek characters to the url.

```
$str = html_entity_decode('&#963;&#954;', ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
// $str is 'σκ'
$str = urlencode($str);
// $str is '%CF%83%CE%BA'

$link = 'http://www.example.com?id=' . $str;
```

Comment: First one gives me: cannot yet handle MBCS in html_entity_decode()!
I guess also only usable on PHP 5

Comment: @phpheini, Seems you're running an older version of PHP, please look in the [comments](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.html-entity-decode.php) of the html_entity_decode for possible solutions - I can't test it for you on my php 5.3.

Comment: Do you mean this function: `function unhtmlentities($string)
         {
          // replace numeric entities
          $string = preg_replace('~&#x([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $string);
          $string = preg_replace('~&#([0-9]+);~e', 'chr("\\1")', $string);
          // replace literal entities
          $trans_tbl = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
          $trans_tbl = array_flip($trans_tbl);
          return strtr($string, $trans_tbl);
         }`

This one gives me a very encrypted result.

Comment: @phpheini, search for "MBCS" on that page, there are more suggestions for solutions. What about `$str = html_entity_decode(utf8_decode('&#963;&#954;'), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: hm, same thing, cannot yet handle MBCS in html_entity_decode()

Comment: @phpheini, what php version are you running? Is upgrading to php5 not an option?

Comment: Hm, weird. This gives me as result `&#963;&#954;`, so nothing changed.
Running PHP 4.4, I rather dont want to update PHP version. There must be a solution without upgrading, mustnt there?

Comment: @phpheini, How about [this workaround](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.html-entity-decode.php#75153)? The output seems ok and _should_ run on php4.

Comment: I dont get how to combine the two functions?

Comment: @phpheini, What do you mean? The first function uses the second one, you just need to use `html_entity_decode_utf8('&#963;&#954;');`. If we're talking about [the ones from the comments](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.html-entity-decode.php#75153).

Comment: Thanks but this gives me as result: `ÏƒÎº`

Comment: @phpheini, I don't know what more to suggest to you except upgrading to php5. Full unicode support is simply useful when working with unicode strings. Sorry, maybe someone else can suggest a better approach.

Comment: Thanks Czechnology! Do you know how to upgrade to PHP5 if you are not running your own server?

Comment: @phpheini: Ask the administrator of your webserver to upgrade. Some hosting providers even have more php installations and user can choose between them in the administration. But that depends - ask your admin or hosting company ;)

Comment: @Czechnology: Ok, thanks. Now what I did is I created a new directory which is now PHP 5.3. But the function `html_entity_decode(utf8_decode('&#963;&#954;'), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');` gives me ÏƒÎº as output. Isnt that weird?

Comment: @phpheini, are you viewing it under unicode encoding? It works fine for me on php5.3. I get `ÏƒÎº` only when viewing it as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @ Czechnology: I just created a php file without any encoding. So maybe ISO-8859-1 is the default. The problem is I wanted to include the php5-file (with html_entity_decode) into another file (php4). And I guess I cant really change the encoding type. Is there no way to make it work with ISO-8859-1? If not I will try changing the mode to UTF-8.

Comment: @phpheini, The encoding of the file itself shouldn't be a problem (since the string `&#963;&#954;` itself is all ASCII, until decoded), I'm talking about the encoding set in the browser or by the html META tags.

Comment: You know what. I thought I could just run the script that is php5 and then get the result into the file with php4. But with include obviously this wont work since the script is then performed in the php4 file. Which alternatives do I have?

PS: with the encoding type UTF-8 the output works (in the php5 file). :)

Comment: @phpheini, Well, you can let the php5 file output the required data and then get the data over http with `file` or `file_get_contents` or cURL (so that it's processed by php first). But I would rather suggest moving your whole application over to php5.

Comment: I just tried to change the whole thing to php5 but there are millions of errors. So I guess I will need some time to change the code and adjust it to the new php version.
If I use file_get_contents, I need to  write something like: file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/php5.php?id=&#963;&#954; dont I?

Comment: @phpheini, `file_get_contents('http://example.com/php5.php?id='.urlencode('&#963;&#954;'));`. But that's just if your server has `allow_url_fopen` set to 'on', otherwise use cURL (please Google for examples if you're not familiar with it). Also please note that this solution might slow down the execution of your script a bit (probably not much - simply test it) so converting your whole application to php5 should still be one of your future goals.

Comment: @Czechnology: You are my man! Thank you so much! Since it is only a small part of my website I will not update to PHP5 right now and I rather used file_get_contents. Now it works perfectly fine, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

try [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) ( string $string [, int $quote_style = ENT_COMPAT ] )

Edit:
On this site where you genereate the URL(parameter) set rawurlencode ( string $str ). Then the url is encoded. Then you can revert it with rawurldecode ( string $str ).

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me an error message Call to undefined function (I guess this function is only for PHP 5)

Comment: But it makes no sense. When you send id=σκ its not escaped with &#963;&#954; so you cannot convert it back?! You should write that you have php4 its (PHP 5 >= 5.1.0).

Comment: You mean to rawurlencode and decode it in the same script? This doesnt seem to work.

Comment: i think so i have understand it you want to send a text over the ip right? So now you have greak letter in the text. So should escape the URL how Czechnology says with urlencode. But i think rawurlencode is better for this. On the other site when you read the $_GET you can make rawurldecode and decode it back to the letters.

Comment: Yes, this would work, if the URL was a script on my site, but I need to have a link to another website www.example.com?id=σκ